# Text Manipulation Batch File logon script

Tags: batch-file

I have an issue with manipulating String to map network drive. What i want to do is:

net use T: \server\"userpath"

but userpath is not the same as %username% but users lastname and first letter of name. So %username% would return John.Smith but userpath above should be SmithJ

Is there anyway to do this in a batch file?

Comment: is it always exactly `firstname.lastname`?  No middle name, no middle initials?

Comment: yes the %username% will always be firstname.lastname. The share name however should be LastnameX where X is First Letter of Firstname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
net use T: "\server\%username:*.=%%username:~0,1%"
```

Should serve.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small batch code to get first and last name separated by a dot from environment variable **USERNAME** and build the user's path on server as requested.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%F in ( "%USERNAME%" ) do (
   set FirstName=%%F
   set UserPath=%%G!FirstName:~0,1!
)
net use T: "\\server\!UserPath!" /persistent:no
endlocal
```